# How to use shift + click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force directed graph using D3 and I have the ability to pan using the click button.
What I wish to do is to hold shift + click to do this.

Now I have this code :

This is seeing if the shift button is clicked whilst I am clicking the mouse:

```
.on("click", function() {
    if (d3.event.shiftKey) {
        console.log("Mouse+Shift pressed");
        svg.append('svg:rect')
    .call(zoom);
    }
})
```

the zoom function:

```
var minZoom = 0.2,
    maxZoom = 2;
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom", redraw)
    .scaleExtent([minZoom, maxZoom])//-call zoom but put scale extent on to limit zoom in/out
    ;
```

redraw function which does the translate and scale:

```
function redraw() {
    inner.attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); 
    }
```

Now, this kind of works. I have put a console log on to debug it and what happens is, when I press shift and mouse click the 'console.log string' only gets printed out when I let go of the mouse button.

But I want it to work when the mouse button is down. I have tried mousedown, mouseover and click, are there  any other ways of doing this ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the .keydown() event of jQuery. It should solve your problems.

Here's the link to the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Hope it was helpful!